# How to target with styling table row :last-child in Full Calendar library

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar, emotion

I'm using Full Calendar library and I have the situation that evens with longer names don't fit content of the single day field.
[image]

To see full event name I solved it that for first six columns : Nie - Pt I change the position with :hover pseudo-class, which makes full name visible.

```
.fc-daygrid-event {
    &:hover {
      position: absolute;
    }
  }
```

But it's not working for last column "Sob".
For last column I wanted to use property white-space:unset. It will work differently but deliver the functionality.
I have tried 3 ideas how to point to :last-child element, but it didn't work.
Can You please suggest how can I select it ?

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

.fc-day-grid .fc-row td:last-child {
    background-color: yellow;
    &:hover {
      white-space: unset;
    }
  }

  .fc-day .fc-day-sun .fc-day-future .fc-daygrid-day {
    background-color: yellow;
    &:last-child {
      :hover {
        white-space: unset;
      }
    }
  }

  .fc-day-grid .fc-row td:nth-of-type(7) {
    background-color: yellow;
    &:hover {
      white-space: unset;
    }
  }
```

Or maybe You can suggest another solution how to fix this behaviour ?

For styling purpose I use emotion/react library:

```
 <StyledCalendar>
        <FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
          initialView="dayGridMonth"
          buttonText={{ today: t('calendar.today') }}
          titleFormat={(date) => monthYearTitleHandler(date)}
          dayHeaderContent={({ date }) => calendarDayNameHandler(date)}
          displayEventEnd
          displayEventTime
          events={mockEvents}
          eventTimeFormat={{
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            meridiem: false,
          }}
        />
      </StyledCalendar>
```

Comment: `But it's now working`...I assume you meant "not" instead of "now"?

Comment: yes, sorry, of course not working, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

to show a full calendar entry on hover using the fullcalendar library you can use

```
.fc-event-title:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

if you want to target a specific column (for example the second) you can use

```
.fc-day:nth-child(2) .fc-event-title:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
```